# React js inline css variable

Tags: reactjs

I wanna give inline css variable to div and use it in my `Style.css` to give different animation delay to my flex boxes. How can i do it. Here are those parts of my code:

`data.js`:

```
export default [
  {
    img: "img-1.jpg",
    varID: 0.3,
  },
  {
    img: "img-2.jpg",
    varID: 0.6,
  },
  {
    img: "img-3.jpg",
    varID: 0.9,
  },

  ...

];
```

`App.js`:

```
import data from './data';
...
<div className="boxes">
  {data.map((item, index) => {
     const { img, varID } = item;
       return (
         <div
           key={index}
           className="box"
           style={{ background: `url(/images-p/${img})`}}> // <-- here
          </div>
        );
      })}
</div>
...
```

My approach was:

```
...
style={{ background: `url(/images-p/${img})`, --order: varID}}>
...
```

But it didn't work. Pls help! Thank you!

Comment: you need to pass it as string like this '--order' not like --order

Comment: What does that variable mean? what is it assigned to, `opacity`?

Comment: yeah, passing it as a string worked: '--order'